# Program running but not displaying result using native android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This is my jni file , `native.cpp`

```
    extern "C"
 Java_org_opencv_samples_NativeActivity_CvNativeActivity_CannyJNI(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,
        jint height, jint width, jintArray in, jintArray out)
{
    //get the data pointer.
    jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
    jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);


    //Build the Mat structure for input data
    Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)_in);
    //Build the Mat structure for output data
    Mat bgr(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)_out);

    //Convert Mat to IplImage
    IplImage mSrcImg = mSrc;
    IplImage mOutImg = bgr;

    //Create the gray image for input data.
    IplImage * mSrcGrayImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&mSrcImg), mSrcImg.depth, 1);
    IplImage * mOutGrayImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&mSrcImg), mSrcImg.depth, 1);

    IplImage *b,*g,*r;
    b = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(mSrcGrayImg), 8, 1 );
    g = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(mSrcGrayImg), 8, 1 );
    r = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(mSrcGrayImg), 8, 1 ) ;

    cvSplit(&mSrcImg, b, g, r, 0 );
    cvEqualizeHist( b, b );
    cvEqualizeHist( g, g );
    cvEqualizeHist( r, r );
    cvMerge(b,g,r,0,&mOutImg);
    //release the pointer.
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);
    return true;
}
```

When i add these two lines my every jni part work for me

```
cvCvtColor(mOutGrayImg, mSrcGrayImg, CV_BGR2YCrCb);
cvCvtColor(mSrcGrayImg, &mOutImg , CV_YCrCb2BGR);
```

like from above code when i add

```
cvMerge(b,g,r,0,mOutGrayImg);
cvCvtColor(mOutGrayImg, mSrcGrayImg, CV_BGR2YCrCb);
cvCvtColor(mSrcGrayImg, &mOutImg , CV_YCrCb2BGR);
```

it runs , and same like my other codes , can anyone please tell me `Why and How` ? and How i can get rid of these two lines and simply `cvMerge(b,g,r,0,mOutGrayImg);` this lines send the output image and how i can set the C++ interface for this code.

Here is my jave file contain `CvNativeActivity.java`

```
public class CvNativeActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2
{   
    public native boolean BrightnessJNI(int width, int height, int [] mPhotoIntArray, int [] mCannyOutArray);

    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("native_activity");
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    ImageView imageview_1;
    ImageView imageview_2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         imageview_1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         imageview_2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        InputStream is;
        is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.foot);
        Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        int [] mPhotoIntArray;
        int [] mCannyOutArray;

        mPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
        // Copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
        bmInImg.getPixels(mPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());

        //create the Brightness result buffer
        mCannyOutArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];

        //
        // Do Brightness
        //
        BrightnessJNI(bmInImg.getHeight(), bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray);

        //
        // Convert the result to Bitmap
        //
        Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
        bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());


        imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);

        //
        // Save the result to file
        //
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        String outFileName = extStorageDirectory + "/Brightness";

        OutputBitmapToFile(bmOutImg, outFileName);





    }

    void OutputBitmapToFile(Bitmap InBm, String Filename)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

        File f = new File(Filename);
        try
        {
            f.createNewFile();
            //write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the issue. It's not showing the image because you have put `alpha channel` as 0 in `cvMerge`. Bitmap is of RGBA format. And the alpha is 0. Hence complete black image.

Here's the C API implementation code. This works.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
    Java_com_fenchtose_equalizehist_EqActivity_eqhist(
            JNIEnv* env, jobject,
            jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
    {
        jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
        jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

        Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
        Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);

        IplImage mSrcImg = mSrc;
        IplImage mOutImg = bgra;

        IplImage *b, *g, *r, *a;

        b = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), mSrcImg.depth, 1);
        g = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), mSrcImg.depth, 1);
        r = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), mSrcImg.depth, 1);
        a = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), mSrcImg.depth, 1);

        cvSplit(&mSrcImg, b, g, r, a);
        cvEqualizeHist(b, b);
        cvEqualizeHist(g, g);
        cvEqualizeHist(r, r);

        cvMerge(b, g, r, a, &mOutImg); // merge alpha layer too
        jint retVal;
        int ret = 1;
        retVal = jint(retVal);

        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);

        return retVal;


    }
}
```

OLD ANSWER:
I copied your Java file. Made some minor changes. (Showed original image in imageView1, changed native function call).

Here's the JNI File.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
    Java_com_example_equalizehist_EqActivity_eqhist(
            JNIEnv* env, jobject,
            jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
    {
        jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
        jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

        Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
        Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4);

        vector<Mat> sChannels;
        split(mSrc, sChannels);

        for(int i=0; i<sChannels.size(); i++)
        {
            equalizeHist(sChannels[i], sChannels[i]);
        }

        merge(sChannels, bgra);

        for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
        {
            memcpy(&(_out[i*width]), &(bgra.data[i*bgra.step]), width*bgra.channels());
        }

        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);

        jint retVal;
        int ret = 1;
        retVal = jint(retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

- Step1: Pass Pixel(int arrays) to native function.
- Step2: Create Mat with input pixels.
- Step3: Create an empty vector to hold each channel of `mSrc` Mat.
- Step4: Split mSrc Mat to sChannels vector.
- Step5: Apply equalizeHist function on each channel. Loop over sChannels vector.
- Step6: Merge all the channels in bgra Mat.
- Step7: Copy data of `bgra` Mat to the array of pixels. For this use `memcpy`. Iterate over each row of `bgra` Mat and copy data of each channel. This is CV_8UC4 Mat. Each channel will have data of 2 bytes. So Each pixel will contain 8 bytes of data.
- Step8: Release arrays.

Here's the screenshot of the app.

[image]

I have put up this code on [GitHub](https://github.com/jayrambhia/EqualizeHist). You might want to check it if you run into any issues.

NOTE: If you're using this code, make sure that you declare the native function correctly.

If you don't want to use `memcpy`, you can directly allocate

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
    Java_com_example_equalizehist_EqActivity_eqhist(
            JNIEnv* env, jobject,
            jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
    {
        jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
        jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

        Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
        Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);

        vector<Mat> sChannels;
        split(mSrc, sChannels);

        for(int i=0; i<sChannels.size(); i++)
        {
            equalizeHist(sChannels[i], sChannels[i]);
        }

        merge(sChannels, bgra);
        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);

        jint retVal;
        int ret = 1;
        retVal = jint(retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Even this is working properly.

Comment: its not working showing error on opencv c++ functions like `split , merge , memcpy` , can we use totally c++ interface with jni ?

Comment: Yes. You can certainly use C++ interface with JNI. You are using extern "C". And try to include proper headers. `memcpy` is not an opencv function. You should post the errors that you are getting.

Comment: i updated my question and award bounty for it if you explain bit , thanks

Comment: @Ahmad This is the C++ interface. The code that you have got is probably from the example MyRealTimeImageProcessing. I'm just guessing that. Anyway, there's nothing much to do to setup the c++ interface. Just start using it. It also helps when you pass Mat address from Java to Native. Both C and C++ interfaces have same Android.mk and Application.mk files.

Comment: @Ahmad I have updated the answer and found the issue.

Comment: Thank you +1 , but can you tell me which java line get the value of `merge(sChannels, bgra);` mean get `bgra` for final result and some of my function is not working with `CV_8UC4` like `bilateral filter` i have to use `CV_8UC3` for it , is there any conversion which is acceptable for both

Comment: Initially convert CV_8UC4 to 3 channel image using cvtColor with CV_RGBA2BGR. After all the processing convert it back to RGBA using cvtcolor with CV_BGR2RGBA.

Comment: why you use this `jint retVal;
        int ret = 1;
        retVal = jint(retVal);
        return retVal;`

Comment: It's just because it returns jint. You can keep it void or jboolean or anything else

Comment: stil getting error on equalizeHist of `invalid argument` on this line `equalizeHist(sChannels[i], sChannels[i]);` using the last part of program

Comment: Sometimes jni gives this issue of indexing vector. That's a bummer. In the loop create a new Mat.` Mat channel = sChannels[I]; equalizeHist(channel, channel); `

Comment: jni is much complicated , i did this for conversion `cvtColor(mSrc , mSrc , CV_BGRA2RGB);` for converting 8UC4 to 8UC3 and then after proceeding i did `cvtColor(mSrc , mSrc , CV_RGB2BGRA);`  but it again didn't work for me !! is there anywhere java playing role in conversions or Mat or Bitmap or thing ?

Comment: and the very last thing that is it affect that we use BGR approach in JNI with opencv but java/android deal it with RGB format , so it may affect the filters ?

Comment: Bitmap is in RGBA. So use.. CV_RGBA2BGR and CV_BGR2RGBA. java/android deals mainly in RGBA. Always convert to RGBA if your bitmap is of type ARGB8888

Comment: @Froyo After `Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4);` and before `env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);` I put the below code and its working but it showing something wrong on the button

Comment: `Mat_<float> aftn(3,3);
 
 aftn << 0,0,0

  ,0,.34,.25

  ,.16,.24,.45;


 cv::transform(mSrc,bgra,aftn);`

Comment: what's wrong on the button? did you set transform size appropriately?

Comment: no , look , when i run this `bilateralFilter(img, out, 5, 5, 50);` , native throw error on bilateralFilter

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make it work ? because it works in my visual studio projects